# Linux fread() call to USB device freezes when exposed to high CPU utilization

Tags: c, linux

Recently I've written a driver for a drawing tablet called the "Boogie Board RIP" to be able to use it as an input device for linux. It can be connected via usb to a computer. When the provided pen is near or touching the device's screen, it will send data telling where the pen is on the screen.

Basically the driver works great. I can write on it as if it was a wacom tablet.

At unpredictable times, the program will hang on the line below and the cursor on my computer screen will stay in place

```
fread(packet, sizeof(char), BYTES, f);
```

Where:

- "packet" is an array of 8 bytes
- "BYTES" is 8
- "f" is a file opened in binary read (rb) mode. In my case it's `/dev/usb/hiddev0`

The basic program layout is a while loop that reads a byte at a time. Below is a mock-up of the much larger thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *path = argv[1];
    unsigned char packet[8];
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "rb");
    int i;

    while (1) {
        fread(packet, sizeof(char), 8, f);
        for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
            printf("%x", packet[i]);
            fflush(stdout);
        }

    }
}
```

I started to notice that my driver would "freeze" more often when I was running more things, like watching youtube, playing music... These aren't great examples. Basically I began to suspect it was related to CPU utilization. So I wrote the program below to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while(1) {
        printf("a");
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Running this "infinite loop" program in a separate terminal while running the other program above in another terminal will result in harshly more frequent freezes. Basically the program will stop at the fread() line without fail within 2 seconds.

I learned that when the call to fread() doesn't get any data I can still read from the device with another instance of that program or simply printing out the contents of the file via `sudo cat /dev/usb/hiddev0`. The original process remains stuck while the new program will spit out the data coming from the device.

It seems as though the file simply closes. But that doesn't make sense because then fread would segfault on the next read. Looking for any ideas.

EDIT:
I solved this by using libusb to deal with reading from my device rather than trying to read directly from the device file.

Comment: "fread would segfault" segfault is not automatic when something goes wrong.

Comment: What is the question ? Why didn't you provide driver code ? Why did you expect that a process with a infinite loop will not take a high amount of CPU ? Why did you write `sizeof(char)` and not `sizeof(unsigned char)` or better `sizeof *packet` ? So many questions !

Comment: Question is why fread() fails to get more data. The infinite loop program I included is only to help the point that this issue is CPU related?

I didn't provide the full driver because the same behavior can be reproduced with the much smaller program supplied.

The driver itself is an infinite loop, but stops at fread() anyways until the next "packet" is sent from the usb device.

Comment: Well, looking by your "mcve", you are not looking for the return value of `fread()`, so I suppose your drivers either. If `fread()` return an error do you stop your driver or do something else ? The correct way to write such loop is generally like that `while (fread(packet, sizeof *packet, sizeof packet / sizeof *packet, f))`

Comment: The return value would not help at all since it's the fact that the function doesn't return which is the problem. The program should hang like I'm describing only when I'm not touching the pen to the device.

Comment: Did `valgrind` return a clean output against your actual code?

Comment: It's hard to say if valgrind works since it's intended that the program be killed with ctrl+c. At least at this point. Running `sudo valgrind ./a.out /dev/usb/hiddev0` and then hitting ctrl+c tells me that `still reachable: 47,569 bytes in 26 blocks`. Could this really affect it? Because fread() will hang at unpredictable times. Running valgrind multiple times will yield the same number of still reachable bytes.

Comment: I would check the return of `fread()`. If it once returns less than 8, this might be for the same reason why a consecutive call hangs... And, if it once returns less than 8, calling `feof()` and `ferror()` (as suggested in [Linux Programmer's Manual - FREAD(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html)) might help to get progress in this issue.

Comment: I ran ferror and feof on my stream after every call to fread and both never returned anything other than 0. Thanks for the tip though.